# Customize TableRow Column Width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a HTML table.

1st row has 5 elements while 2nd row has only 3 elements.

[image]

---

Why 3 columns of the 2nd row gets the width same as width of respective columns in previous row?

I mean since there are only 3 columns in 2nd row, are they not supposed to auto-resize to fill the row?

I tried setting the width of 2nd column in 2nd row, but that **ALSO** increases width of 2nd column in 1st row, which I don't want.

Any help appreciated.

---

### EDIT

[image]
**Required output**

Comment: paste your html, it gives better idea

Comment: @satindersingh  There are 5 `<td>` in 1st `<tr>` and 3 `<td>` in 2nd `<tr>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey now used  to `colspan`

as like this

```
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr class="blue">
<td width="35%"></td>
<td width="15%">SignUp</td>
<td width="15%">Create Blog</td>
<td width="15%">Custimize Blog</td>
<td width="15%">Success</td>
</tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td class="blue2">Create Blog</td>
<td class="blue3">Custimize Blog</td>
<td class="blue4">Success</td>
      </tr></table>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

**Css**

```
table tr td{
text-align:center;
}
.blue{
background:lightblue;
}


.blue2{
background:red;
}


.blue3{
background:blue;
}
.blue4{
background:green;
}
```

live demo http://tinkerbin.com/vqnhht02

and now change to `width` or `height` according to **your design**

Comment: No, this will make 1st column of 2nd row equivalent to 3 columns of 2nd row, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
`<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr class="blue">
    <td width="20%"></td>
    <td width="15%"></td>
    <td width="15%">SignUp</td>
    <td width="15%">Create Blog</td>
    <td width="15%">Custimize Blog</td>
    <td width="15%">Success</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="blue" colspan="2">Create Blog</td>
    < td class="blue" colspan="2">Custimize Blog</td>
    <td class="blue" colspan="2">Success</td>
  </tr>
</table>`
```

Give the background color as per your need.

This width issue is fixed I think.